# Information from the sales_flat_order table

Tags: php, magento

I need to get some information from the **sales_flat_order** table to show in an html file about payment information for orders. How can I? I tried using some PHP code but it did not return anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please show your attempts when asking a question so that we can actually help you with a problem rather than doing the work for you. >  "I tried using some PHP code but it did not return anything."

Comment: If you're using a database you need to run PHP to pull information. Firstly change your .html extension to .php and try and run the PHP query again. You need to show your code of what doesn't work. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: paste the php code u used

Comment: Hello,

I do not really have any code ready, everyone I tried did not work and I deleted the files.

But I appreciate your feedback and sorry for my lack of manners.

Comment: unfortunately we can't help without any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a base example to get you started with PHP. If you need to get queries from a database this is the most suitable option.

Firstly, change your file extension to .php not .html

Then:

Create your database connect file:

```
/**
 * database.php
 */
class Database
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "dbname";
    private $username = "username";
    private $password = "password";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

I then suggest making a dbCommon.php file:

```
/**
 * dbCommon.php
 */

require_once ('database.php');

class DBCommon
{
    private $conn;

    /** @var Common */
    public $common;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

You can add things from bootstrap such as:

```
public function error($message)
    {
        $this->messages[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $message . '</div>';
    }
```

within the dbCommon.php file.

After you've made these you will then need to make yourself a class file to add your logic to. Here's a basic example of how your code should look:

```
/**
 * class.queries.php
 */

require_once ('dbCommon.php');

class queries extends DBCommon
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
    }

    public function sales()
    {
        $stmt = $this->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order`");
        $stmt->execute();

        $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $res;
    }
}
```

FINALLY, after this you then need to go back into the file.php (originally .html) and add this into the top:

```
<?php

require_once ('class.queries.php');

$fetch = new queries();

$info = $fetch->sales();

?>
```

This now means you can fetch information as and how you choose to and you'd simply echo out `$info->columnName`

I'm not trying to wipe your nose for you but hopefully this will give you guidance to get into PDO and performing PHP queries correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i´ll try